# An error occurred. please try again while in app billing testing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test in-app-billing application(i use in app billing version 2). For that i follow guide as per link http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html.

i upload my signed apk to google market as draft, publish item. 
But when i am going to test in app billing it gives me error "An error occurred. please try again".

I am testing it on Sony experia U with Android 2.3.7 and my google play store version 3.4.7

please suggest me.......

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check are u added the internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml  file.

You must add internet and billing permission in androidmanifest.xml file.

### Androidmanifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />`

and add below billing service after activity close

```
 <service android:name=".BillingService" />

    <receiver android:name=".BillingReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And must keep public key in security.java class

```
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA09UpyecYDEoQTTp+MCZmJGuRtphynUhGzRvl/jiCPRbdfzrt649RB5j8OmADlkB2pu3TiN/wxKoqol0Gadw7W+BhkTgptog2ZkRrFqnVq+DJSbL1cXbQAc549VmSTEhMSRA0FkpiEg/eqBjyDKiFsMHlmO21WwYyXGvNj5b4qt6OUrbYZYUuO0RHbOJeaJEfoYWuGpxHHUVf0jmQG/+UWOkfNzesRmzAwlz2fPIxchE8k0kSV7dHWP4XaIt7f0tMzny3GsXTBJEJpqXydoCjRWJeOUZX9BjK6U/yPCoTikxA3V7NaSCZ0ofZMJeXsuxhy1TEmW88q6ayhOx/wEKDBwIDAQAB";
```